# Avoid simultaneous shopping from same user through paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am thinking about perfect logic for a task. There are 3 pages in total written in php. product_select, cart_summary, thank_you

**Control flow:**

1. user selects products from first page and clicks continue button
2. in "cart_summary" page total cost and list of products selected is displayed. user then clicks "pay with paypal" button
3. user is taken to paypal page. make transaction. then from paypal user is redirected to thank_you page
4. in thank_you page a mail is sent to user and admin related to product details

I did the coding. now when user clicks on continue button in step 1, all the products selected are stored in a session. when user reaches thank_you page, the value in session is sent as mail.

**Problem with this method:**
1. user selects product worth USD 100. visits paypal page to make the transaction. now the user is in paypal page.
2. at that time user takes another tab and takes product_select page. then selects products worth USD300 and clicks continue button. now the value in session is USD 300
3. in first tab when user comes back from paypal after making payment for USD 100, a mail is sent with purchase details of second order as session contains second order details.

Hope i could make my point clear. please help me with right logic to tackle this situation.

Comment: disable the shopping cart as part of the "click here to go to paypal" link. "sorry, you've started checkout. no more ordering for you. back of the line"

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use PayPal's IPN which would confirm exactly what was purchased and for how much:
https://www.paypal.com/ipn The IPN will inform your website/listener the transaction details that have occurred so it wouldn't matter what was done to the cart after they'd gone through to PayPal.

Alternatively, at the point of redirecting to PayPal, you could store the contents of the shopping cart in a database and then restore them when the user comes back to your site before proceeding with the email. The restored contents would overwrite any changes that occurred meanwhile.